# gradle run TestNG test cause "Error occurred during initialization of VM"

Tags: gradle, testng

I have one test framework project which was created via Gradle/Idea, and since this project is one test framework project and all the test cases were located under the src/main/java folder.

```
sourceSets{
test{
java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
}
}
```

By Using gradle, I want to create one new task in build.gradle to run the specified testNG xml file via command line.

```
task runTest(type: Test){
useTestNG(){}
}
```

but always I got error like the below.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError : java/lang/Object
```

Could anyone support this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: why your test sourcesets point to main ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your tests are in main it is not ideal but well yes you can amend the default sourcesets.

```
sourceSets.test.java.srcDir 'src/main/java'
```

if you run it from IntelliJ you can add

```
idea.module {
    testSourceDirs += file('src/main/java')
}
```

As intelliJ is not very good with stuff like gradle source sets.

About your error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError : java/lang/Object
```

Is your `PATH` / `JAVA_HOME` set? It seems like it might not be.